# strange heap out of memory nodejs

Tags: node.js, memory-leaks, heap-memory

My node server is getting heap out of memory now n then. I tried so hard to debug but problem is still same. 
I am getting this error

```
FATAL ERROR: CALL_AND_RETRY_LAST Allocation failed - JavaScript heap out of memory
4|app |  1: node::Abort() [node /home/app/server.js]
4|app |  2: 0x1356bec [node /home/app/server.js]
4|app |  3: v8::Utils::ReportOOMFailure(char const*, bool) [node /home/app/server.js]
4|app |  4: v8::internal::V8::FatalProcessOutOfMemory(char const*, bool) [node /home/app/server.js]
4|app |  5: v8::internal::Factory::NewFixedArray(int, v8::internal::PretenureFlag) [node /home/app/server.js]
4|app |  6: v8::internal::OrderedHashTable<v8::internal::OrderedHashSet, 1>::Allocate(v8::internal::Isolate*, int, v8::internal::PretenureFlag) [node /home/app/server.js]
4|app |  7: v8::internal::OrderedHashTable<v8::internal::OrderedHashSet, 1>::Rehash(v8::internal::Handle<v8::internal::OrderedHashSet>, int) [node /home/app/server.js]
4|app |  8: v8::internal::OrderedHashTable<v8::internal::OrderedHashSet, 1>::EnsureGrowable(v8::internal::Handle<v8::internal::OrderedHashSet>) [node /home/app/server.js]
4|app |  9: v8::internal::Runtime_SetGrow(int, v8::internal::Object**, v8::internal::Isolate*) [node /home/app/server.js]
4|app | 10: 0x7a8879046fd
```

also sometimes this error

```
4|app | <--- Last few GCs --->
4|app |
4|app | [11385:0x2b893d0]   764692 ms: Mark-sweep 1398.5 (1871.3) -> 1398.5 (1871.3) MB, 27920.5 / 2.1 ms  allocation failure GC in old space requested
4|app | [11385:0x2b893d0]   789281 ms: Mark-sweep 1398.5 (1871.3) -> 1398.3 (1797.3) MB, 24586.0 / 4.6 ms  last resort
4|app | [11385:0x2b893d0]   797403 ms: Mark-sweep 1398.3 (1797.3) -> 1398.3 (1758.8) MB, 8119.9 / 1.0 ms  last resort
4|app |
4|app |
4|app | <--- JS stacktrace --->
4|app |
4|app | ==== JS stack trace =========================================
4|app |
4|app | Security context: 0x7e7bf028799 <JSObject>
4|app |     1: add [native collection.js:~111] [pc=0x7a887d1b539](this=0x13ebc6615671 <Set map = 0x18534a9053d9>,p=0x1d9c6aee7719 <String[24]: 5b9827afc5635e2a08f49b6f>)
4|app |     2: baseUniq [/home/app/node_modules/waterline/node_modules/lodash/index.js:~2670] [pc=0x7a887d4d51a](this=0x243308d07421 <JSGlobal Object>,array=0x13ebc66154d9 <JSArray[469241]>,iteratee=0x13ebc6615531 <JSFunction (sfi = 0x3fc29...
```

Please help me find which code is blowing up the heap. I tried tools to find out leaks but it only tells memory is leaked not where.

Comment: Are you sure it's a memory leak? i.e. you could first try to increase the max-heap size and see if the error still happens. If yes, maybe check this link which helped me a lot when I had the same problem -> https://blog.risingstack.com/case-study-node-js-memory-leak-in-ghost/

Comment: Thanks I will update after increasing heap size

Comment: As @eol said, try running node --max-old-space-size=8192 <your-entrypoint>.js. We can't really figure out where the leak happens from error you are getting.

Comment: I got some idea where leak is happening it's a third party library (waterline.js) to query the db. Still testing things. What does old-space means in v8 land? @BrankoZivanovic

Comment: By default, your nodejs process can take 512MB maximum, and when you exceed it's going to crash, just like it did. You can use node --max-old-space-size=2048 index.js to increase it to 2gb or higher, and see if it crashes then, or you may not even be able to profile CPU usage without it if you can't even start a script properly. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

It was third party ORM library called Waterline.js the configuration was misconfigured there was redundant mapping between collection so addition of any document into db goes and checks for the document belonged to which user or so. And collection happen to have 130K+ documents so it fetches all in memory I think and ran the code.